# pgfplots: Manual examples for \addplot3[surf] look different when I compile them

Tags: pgfplots

- I must do something wrong :).
- Today, I tried the `\addplot3[surf]` feature for the first time.
- Naturally, I played with the examples from the manual.
- When I **copy and paste** some of the examples and compile them (locally and on Overleaf) then the result is different from the manual (no surface, just lines).
- Can you reproduce the issue and do you see my mistake?

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[
    border=5pt, 
    multi={tikzpicture}
    ]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[mesh/ordering=x varies]
% this yields a 3x4 matrix in `x varies'
% ordering:
\addplot3 [surf] coordinates {
(0,0,0) (1,0,0) (2,0,0) (3,0,0)
(0,1,0) (1,1,0.6) (2,1,0.7) (3,1,0.5)
(0,2,0) (1,2,0.7) (2,2,0.8) (3,2,0.5)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[mesh/ordering=y varies]
% this yields a 3x4 matrix in column-wise ordering:
\addplot3[surf]coordinates {
(0,0,0) (0,1,0) (0,2,0)
(1,0,0) (1,1,0.6) (1,2,0.7)
(2,0,0) (2,1,0.7) (2,2,0.8)
(3,0,0) (3,1,0.5) (3,2,0.5)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[colorbar]
\addplot3 [
surf,
faceted color=blue,
samples=15,
domain=0:1,y domain=-1:1
] {x^2 - y^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blank lines are important - they tell PGFPlots how many rows/coloums there are in your data:

With blank lines:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot3[surf] coordinates {
(0,0,0) (1,0,0) (2,0,0) (3,0,0)

(0,1,0) (1,1,0.6) (2,1,0.7) (3,1,0.5)

(0,2,0) (1,2,0.7) (2,2,0.8) (3,2,0.5)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Without blank lines, but explicit setting number of rows:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot3[surf, mesh/rows=3] coordinates {
(0,0,0) (1,0,0) (2,0,0) (3,0,0)
(0,1,0) (1,1,0.6) (2,1,0.7) (3,1,0.5)
(0,2,0) (1,2,0.7) (2,2,0.8) (3,2,0.5)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 3D Surface plot]

Manual page 34:

> Note that we there is no need to configure either mesh/rows=⟨N⟩ or
> mesh/cols=⟨N⟩ here because these parameters are automatically deduced
> from the scan line lengths marked by empty lines in our input file.

(-or in your case not in a file, but in the `coordinates`)

Comment: Thanks! I just copied and pasted the code and did not pay enough attention!